# How to test if file is_writable and not locked by another program

Tags: php

This sounds like a duplicate of [PHP is_writeable or opened by another program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536911/php-is-writeable-or-opened-by-another-program) but that didn't answer my question.

My program suddenly stopped working with a huge error message. After a bit of investigation it turned out that it was trying to write to a file which was open in another application. How can I test for this without generating an error? I'd like to replace the PHP automatic error with a user-friendly error. `fopen($filename, 'c');` fails (any writing option such as `'w'` or `'a'` also fails), only `'r'` works but it is not helpful as the file is not locked for reading. I've tried `flock`ing the file with `LOCK_EX` which as php.net says is

> to acquire an exclusive lock (writer)

but unfortunately, this says that the lock has been acquired! I'm guessing `LOCK_EX` can only be used in conjunction with `fopen` when using one of `'w'`, `'a'`, `'c'`, etc. (which as I said before always fails). `is_readable()` and `is_writable()` both return `true`. I understand that in *normal* circumstances the file would be writable but I want to know if it's writable write now!

So far every method I've tried has either given incorrect results or an error (warning). And please, please, please don't suggest using `@`!

Comment: If `flock()` doesn't work, it means the other application doesn't use advisory locking.

Answer (score 0):

If you check that you can write it now, and then open it for writing, another process or thread could have opened it in between, so that gives you a race condition. Instead, try to open it and handle the failure.

In this case, handling the error might involve a call to `set_error_handler()` to keep the output from the logs and another call to `restore_error_handler()` to restore the previous state. Alternatively, using the `@` prefix might really be an alternative, as horrible as it normally is.

The core issue is that PHP's error-handling by logging is flawed, because it requires programs that correctly check for errors to jump through extra loops in order to keep faults that are properly handled out of the logs. Pick a different language (with a different set of flaws) if you want.

Comment: Actually, it's the other way around. The other program had the file open before the PHP script was run. So the file is not writable for the whole time that PHP is trying to access it. I agree that it's flawed that `fopen()` both returns `false` to indicate failure _and_ throws a warning!